# Regex AND operator in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics, re2

I'm trying to use a regex to combine 2 rules into one in Google Analytics. I have the following campaign names:

```
USA - Apparel - search
USA - Shoes - search
USA - Accessories - search
USA - Apparel - display
USA - Shoes - display
```

I'm looking to match only the campaigns that contain `USA` and `- search` in their name.

Right now I managed to do this setup by applying some rules in their User interface, however I'm looking for a way to apply a regex to combine the 2 rules into 1.

[image: Existing rule in Google Analytics]

I tried `(USA)(\-\ search)` and also `(USA)(search)` but no results were returned.

Note: Google Analytics uses the [RE2 Syntax](http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USA \-.*?\- search
```

Should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\bUSA\b.*\bsearch\b|\bsearch\b.*\bUSA\b
```

If the hyphen must be in between, you can use

```
\bUSA\s*-.*-\s*\b(search|display)\b|\b(search|display)\s*-.*-\s*USA
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vR8pD9/1)

Since RE2 does not have look-around support, you cannot use a more sophisticated regex to check for the 2 words in any order.

Note that `\b` means a word boundary to enable whole word matching.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking this for Google Analytics, correct? You can use:

```
(usa)(.*)(-\ssearch)
```

You can use it without the parentheses as well. It only searches for all strings that have `usa` preceding search, no matter what comes in between. If you are not particular about the order, you should create an `OR` filter as well, like:

```
USA.*-\ssearch|-\ssearch.*usa
```